# ASP.NET MVC 5 empty ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, linq, model, null, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a table with [QuestionID] [Description] [User_id].

```
public int QuestionID { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public ApplicationUser user { get; set; }
```

The question is stored in the database when a user sends a question using a form and all the fields are saved correctly.

I send a list from my QuestionController with all the questions to my view:

```
return View(db.Questions.ToList());
```

In my view I use that list:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="td-title">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.user.id)
        </td>
   </tr>
...
```

Everything works except the item.user.id which shows no value (it is filled in the database). How come this is empty? And what can I do to show the user information?

Edit:

I use code-first and this is how I fill in the database:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "QuestionID,Description")] Question question)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        question.user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        db.Questions.Add(question);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(question);
}
```

Example of database result after form:

```
[QuestionID]  [Description]  [user_Id]
      1          blalbla..    397d27d...
```

Comment: Is the ID empty in your controller before you pass it to the view? Why aren't you using a view model? - The serialisation of 'complex' objects (nested / layered in your case) is often not carried out well by MVC)... try simplifying what you are passing to the view into one flat ViewModel object. OR try something like ((ApplicationUser)item.user).id

Comment: When I get one Question object from the database in the same controller where the list is made, it also gives a empty user (although it is not empty is database). So the best practice would be to use a View Model and remove the ApplicationUser from my Question Model?

Comment: show the code you use to populate db.Questions firstly. Are you using EntityFramework? If so and ApplicationUser is an entity then you possibly don't have navigation properties setup correctly for the Question (using a foreign key) to the ApplicationUser, or the query you are using to retrieve the information is incorrect, or mappings in EF are not correct, if you used datbase first they should be correct, if you used code first then it could be a bug.

Comment: Edited question so you can now see how I populate and what the result it. It looks like everything is working fine on the creating-fase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try "public **virtual** ApplicationUser user { get; set; }" ?

I think you have to make it virtual to access ApplicationUser properties or change the code in your view to "@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.user)"